# Cookie sharing between multiple WKWebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, wkwebview

I create a few WkWebViews in my app, but when cookies are set for one webview, they do not take effect in the other ones (i.e. the other webviews do not pass the same cookie back to the server). How can I get them to all use the same cookie storage?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Got this working by using the same WKProcessPool for all the webviews.

First create a process pool *once* somewhere:

```
processPool = [[WKProcessPool alloc] init];
```

Then use it when creating WKWebviews. The pool must be set in the init method, not afterwards.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
config.processPool = processPool;
webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:config];
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work in my case where i have hybrid app. Login webpage stores cookies in singleton processpool and later on in other page it will pickup cookies (sessionid, authenticationdata) from same singleton processpool.

Comment: Do you know, will it anyhow affect performance of WKWebView if you're loading two at the same time?

Comment: on iOS10, by default, cookies are shared between multiple WKWebView. I have verified this on iOS10 simulator, but not sure whether it's true or not on iOS8/9

Comment: @ikzjfr0 are you sure about what you're saying? I tried today on iOS 10 and I need the shared pool instance if I want to keeps cookies shared between wkwebview.

Comment: @FabrizioDuroni i'm serious, at least it's true on simulators

Comment: I've seen the same - don't need WKProcessPool in simulator, but need it on device.

Comment: how about if user restart app , in this case processpool object initialize again then how cookies sync ?

Comment: Today in iOS 13+ this issue is still hanging around. Does anybody has a solution that persist?