# WKProcessPool can be permanently stored using NSUserDefaults or something else?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cookies, wkwebview

Thanks to the bellow question's answer, I figured out how to use Cookies between multiple WKWebView by using WKProcessPool.

[Cookie sharing between multiple WKWebViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797972/cookie-sharing-between-multiple-wkwebviews/)

And then I'm now trying to permanently store the WKProcessPool object (of my singleton object) by using NSUserDefaults.

I've got the following error.
`Attempt to insert non-property list object`

So I tries to fix the error by converting WKProcessPool object into NSData by NSKeyedArchiver.
But It cannot be done because WKProcessPool does not implement `encodeWithCoder:` and `init:aDecoder`.

How can I solve this problem to store WKProcessPool object permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html) for your custom objects. Here is     [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data)

---

#### Edit:

I really didn't have idea that [`WKProcessPool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKProcessPool_Ref/index.html) is in built class, since apple doesn't implemented the `NSCoding` in it and I can't even see the public properties of this class, so even if you subclass it, you don't have any idea which properties to encode/decode.

You need to find out other solution instead of archiving/archiving the objects. Even if you achieve something using **category** I'm afraid that you will get the expected result.

Comment: You mean that I should make a subclass of WKProcessPool object and implement NSCoding?

If so, I tried before but I can't figure out how to do that.
If possible, show me the overview of your implementation.

Comment: ``extension WKProcessPool {
    convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        aDecoder.decodeObject()
        self.init()
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self)
    }
}
``
I tried to implement NSCoding methods through ``extension``. But this will recreate new object each time even if it uses ``initWithCoder:`` initializer.
How can I implement correctly?