# i want cookie share on multi wkwebview. but it can't well. objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, share, wkwebview

My app is using UIWebview but the UIWebview have a lot of problem.

So i'm transporting from UIWebview to WKWebview.

My issue is cookie.

My app is using multiple WKWebview.

Cookie is did not share in WKWebviews and cookie create is very strange.

Who knows about this?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797972/cookie-sharing-between-multiple-wkwebviews

Comment: thx for your comment. but i already using processPool.

Comment: main Wkwebview -> push sub wkWebview ( cookie create here ) -> pop -> main Wkwebview (try read cookie. but it can't ). this is my case.

Comment: Might get some help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview

Comment: thx~~~!! i try it~ :D

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: Yes~thx for your help~ :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using a shared `WKWebViewConfiguration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore` to set cookies and pass the configuration to the WKWebView-s on creation. See the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534854/1009546